# How to use a variable from another function？

Tags: php, yii

I want to use another variable from another function，

I am tried to use the global variable, but I faild.

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public $file;// declare my $file varable

    function actionIndex()
    {
        $dir = Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.uploads');

        $uploaded = false;
        $model=new Upload();

        if(isset($_POST['Upload']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Upload'];
            global $file; //use the $file varable

            $file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
                 //get a instance into $file varable.

            if($model->validate()){
                $uploaded = $file->saveAs($dir.'/'.$file->getName());
            }
        }
        $this->render('index', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'uploaded' => $uploaded,
                'dir' => $dir,
        ));
    }

    public function actionDownload(){

        var_dump($file);exit; //here printed out a null

        $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('/yiiroot/trackstar/protected/uploads/')."23602414.pdf";

        $upload=new Upload();

        $upload->downloadFile($path);
    }
}
```

I declared a `$file` varable and assigned an instance into it in the `functin actionIndex`. Then, I want to use the `$file` varable at function actionDownload in order to print out the return value of `$file->getname();`

But, I got a null when I "var_dump($file);exit;" in function actionDownload.
Could you help me?

I tried to change my code like:

function actionIndex()
    {

```
        $this->file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');

        ...
}
```

But, in "actionDownload()".

public function actionDownload(){

```
    var_dump($this);exit;
```

...
}

When I "var_dump($this);exit;" as above, I could't get the value of 'file'. It printed out as below:

```
E:\projects\yiiroot\trackstar\protected\controllers\UploadController.php:37:
object(UploadController)[10]
  public 'file' => null
  public 'layout' => string '//layouts/column1' (length=17)
  public 'menu' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'breadcrumbs' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'defaultAction' => string 'index' (length=5)
  private '_id' (CController) => string 'upload' (length=6)
  private '_action' (CController) => 
    object(CInlineAction)[11]
      private '_id' (CAction) => string 'download' (length=8)
      private '_controller' (CAction) => 
        &object(UploadController)[10]
      private '_e' (CComponent) => null
      private '_m' (CComponent) => null
  private '_pageTitle' (CController) => null
  private '_cachingStack' (CController) => null
  private '_clips' (CController) => null
  private '_dynamicOutput' (CController) => null
  private '_pageStates' (CController) => null
  private '_module' (CController) => null
  private '_widgetStack' (CBaseController) => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

Could you help me.

Comment: Why don't you use `$this` keyword?

Comment: I solved this problem according below tipic. [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894174/how-to-print-out-a-value-of-object/53894379#53894379)

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a `public $file` property into your `UploadController` class.
So why not just use `$this` keyword?
You can access your `$file` property wherever you want just by writing:

```
$this->file
```

For example:

```
$this->file = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
```

Comment: I tried to use "$this->file " but when I "var_dump($this->file);exit;" I got a null,

Comment: $this->file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
   
   $file=$this->file;
   /* var_dump($file);exit; */
   if($model->validate()){
    $uploaded = $file->saveAs($dir.'/'.$file->getName());
   }
  }
  $this->render('index', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'uploaded' => $uploaded,
    'dir' => $dir,
  ));
 }
 
 public function actionDownload(){
  
  var_dump($this->file);exit;
  
  $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('/yiiroot/trackstar/protected/uploads/')."23602414.pdf";
    
  $upload=new Upload();
  
  $upload->downloadFile($path);
 }
}

Comment: Could you tell me why I got a null? In public function actionDownload(){
  
  var_dump($this->file);exit;...}    Thank you.

Comment: Because your `$file` property is empty. Firstable, you need to write someting to it using your `function actionIndex()`

Comment: i think it's better to declare `actionIndex()` as `public` method, because you do an ugly things. 
Firstable you should call `public function actionIndex()` to fill your $file property and the you can use it via `$this->file` in your `actionDownload()` method. 
GLHF! ;3

Comment: Not need to pass variables between functions like Zain Farooq advices (guy who also answered this question)

Comment: Thank you, I changed my approach to pass a parameter from front to the "actionDownload($id)",  I can got an object by "var_dump($this->file);exit;" in my front as below.E:\projects\yiiroot\trackstar\protected\views\upload\index.php:22:
object(CUploadedFile)[17]
  private '_name' => string '23602414.pdf' (length=12)
  private '_tempName' => string 'D:\wamp\tmp\php33CA.tmp' (length=23)
  private '_type' => string 'application/pdf' (length=15)
  private '_size' => int 181004
  private '_error' => int 0
  private '_e' (CComponent) => null
  private '_m' (CComponent) => null

Comment: I want to know, how to print out the "private '_name' => string '23602414.pdf'"? I tried to use "$this->file->name", but I got a non object error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to declare `$file` as a global variable. Just declare it in your class and then you can use it in any function of a class with `$this` keyword as `$this` refers to the class you are in. Like in `actionIndex` function.

```
 $this->file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file');
```

And in `actionDownload()`

```
public function actionDownload(){

    var_dump($this->file);exit; //here printed out a null

    $path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('/yiiroot/trackstar/protected/uploads/')."23602414.pdf";

    $upload=new Upload();

    $upload->downloadFile($path);
}
```

[What does the variable $this mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php)

Here is another reference [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483675/in-php-how-to-call-a-variable-inside-one-function-that-was-defined-previously)

Comment: Thank you, I rewrited my code as you said, but in var_dump($this->file);exit; I got a error:" Undefined variable: file". Could you tell me why?

Comment: Ok, then you can return value in `actionIndex` function and then use that value by passing as a parameter inside `actionDownload` function

Comment: Thank you, but when my frontend call the "r=upload/download" I must passing a parameter to "public function actionDownload()" too? Because the frontend will call the "actionDownload()" directly, I don't know how to pass a parameter from actionIndex() to actionDownload(). Could you tell me more detaily?

Comment: You must have to call both of the functions. First, assign `actionDownload()` to a variable and then you can pass it to `actionDownload()`

Comment: Thats an easy way for you